# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'height'

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the height of a BST but it is giving error like `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'height'`. I can't figure out the error.

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.root = val
    def insert(self,data):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = BST(data)
        elif data > self.root:
            if self.right == None:
                self.right = BST(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)
        elif data < self.root:
            if self.left == None:
                self.left = BST(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
    def inorder(self):
        if self.left != None:
            self.left.inorder()
        print(self.root)
        if self.right != None:
            self.right.inorder()
    def height(self):
        if self.root == None:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + max(self.left.height(), self.right.height())

t = BST(4)
t.insert(1)
t.insert(7)
t.insert(3)
t.insert(6)
t.insert(2)
t.insert(5)
t.inorder()
print(t.height())
```

Comment: you should add some checks inside the method `height`, `self.left` or `self.right` could be `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your init method to be this:

```
def __init__(self,val):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.root = val
    self.rheight = 0
    self.lheight = 0
```

And your height method to be this:

```
def height(self):
    if self.root == None:
        return 0
    else:
        if hasattr(self.left, 'height'):
            self.lheight = self.left.height()
        if hasattr(self.right, 'height'):
            self.rheight = self.right.height()
        return 1 + max(self.lheight, self.rheight)
```

The reason this needs to change is, you are calling height all the way down your tree, thus getting all the way to `None` on the right and left sides, all the way at the bottom of the tree. So what this does is check if `self.right` and `self.left` have the attribute of height. They won’t if the type is `None`, so when both are `None`, we return all the way back out.

Answer (score 1):

When you get to this line

```
return 1 + max(self.left.height(), self.right.height())
```

Then at some point, `self.left` becomes not defined (though not at the very start). You can check this by adding `print(self.left)` just before that statement, and you will see `None` outputted just before the error message.

This means that while `self.root` is defined, your base case needs to includes `self.left` (and possibly `self.right`), so that at no point are any of those None.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
return 1 + max(self.left.height(), self.right.height())
```

with

```
if hasattr(self.left, 'height'):
    left_height = self.left.height()
if hasattr(self.right, 'height'):
    right_height = self.right.height()
return 1 + max(left_height, right_height)
```